# django endless pagination - improve performance as many calls at a time

Tags: python, django, django-endless-pagination

I integrated django endless pagination in my app. I have followed the normal procedure provided by its docs. But, I have a doubt. Since, many calls will be done, as we go down the page, I think I should worry about performance here. But, I dont really know what to do.

Will provide more information if necessary.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the number of calls being made (which you shouldn't be unless it is a bottlneck for your application), you could [increase the number of items per page](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#settings) in your settings.py file

`ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE = x`

you could also accomplish this using the [`paginate`](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html#paginate) tag